# Sharepoint Online migration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

my company is migrating our sharepoint to sharepoint online. What are some issues I should look out for?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you study the guides and tips and tricks from ShareGate as that will provide a good foundation for the decisions you will have to make